# The Cauchy problem for Laplace equation in unit cube

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

Here is the question:

We are given a laplace equation $\Delta u=0$ in $Q:=(0,1)\times(0,1)$.

Q1: What are some conditions you can put on this to get uniqueness/existence?

Q2:What if you wanted to prescribe $u(x,0)=f(x)$ and $u_y(x,0)=g(x)$ on $[0,1]\times\{0\}$? What about the existence and uniqueness?

For Q1 I simply put $u(x,y)=f(x,y)$ on the boundary of $Q$, and we require that $f$ is continuous on $\partial Q$. Hence by Perron method, we have both existence and uniqueness of $u$.

But I stuck on Q2. This one looks to me is a Cauchy problem, or part of it... But anyway, here is what I tried so far.

For simplicity, I assume $f$ and $g$ are all $C^\infty$ and I define a new function $\bar{g}$ such that $g=\bar g$ on $[0,1]\times \{0\}$ and 
$$ \int_{\partial Q}\bar g \,d\mathcal H^1=0 $$ 
so that at least I match the requirement for $u$ being the solution of $\Delta u=0$ in $Q$.

My next job is to define $\bar f$ on $\partial Q$ such that $f=\bar f$ on $[0,1]\times \{0\}$ and hence we could use, maybe Perron again, to solve this equation. However, once $\bar f$ is fixed, then $u$ will be determent completely by $\bar f$ and hence I can not control what is $u_y(x,0)$, it will be determent by $f$ but not $g$...

I guess may be I should build some special $\bar f$ so that $\bar f$ is somehow related to $g$? I am not sure... Please help me here!

Also, what about uniqueness? In my opinion, if we have a solution, then this solution has to be unique. This is the fact that if $u=\partial_\nu u =0$ on the smooth part of boundary then $u\equiv0$. Actually, this is an exercise one can find in Gilbert and Trudinger.

Comment: Pedantically speaking the Perron method may not provide a classical solution. Certainly the boundary can only be thin here at the corners, but I suspect it may actually be thin at the corners. So unless you have compatibility between the intersecting boundary segments, the condition being enforced at the corners may not be satisfied.

Comment: Also, it may help to view your Cauchy problem as the wave equation with imaginary velocity. That may clarify why the behavior seems unusual.

Comment: @Ian I thought as long as I have exterior ball condition then my domain is regular enough and hence the Perron method will work. As in this case, at corner point $z=(x,y)$, I can put a ball $B$ such that $B\cap Q=\{z\}$, no?

Comment: @Ian hmm, I am not very familiar with complex analysis but I will try your suggestion with imaginary velocity...

Comment: You're right about the Perron method here, my mistake. I misremembered where exactly the ball has to "fit" in the exterior ball condition.

Comment: If Perron method does not work, I really do not have any other idea how to show existence here. I believe that trying to build a Green function on a unit cube would be a pain...but, well, it might be doable!

Comment: No no, it works fine. If we're dealing with $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ then the ball $B((-1,-1),\sqrt{2})$ is an exterior ball for $(0,0)$. We can do the same for the other corners. Away from the corners everything is easy because the boundary is smooth away from the corners. Again I apologize for the unnecessary digression.

Comment: By the way, may I ask what your reference for the Perron method was? Mine was *Classical Potential Theory* by Armitage and Gardiner. I am interested because I may want a different text for when I start reading about fine topologies.

Comment: @Ian I am using my notes taken from my PDE class...But my professor says that this book by Axler, Bourdon, Ramey's book "Harmonic Function Theory" is a good reference for Perron method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Uniqueness

To show uniqueness holds in Q2, it suffices to prove that only the zero function matches the boundary condition $u=u_y=0$. A harmonic function can be reflected across a line segment where it vanishes, by $u(x,-y)=-u(x,y)$. Indeed, this preserves the local mean value property both on the boundary and away from it. Now we have a harmonic function in $(0,1)\times (-1,1)$ such that both $u$ and $u_y$ vanish on $(0,1)\times \{1\}$; hence $u_x=0$ too. A quick way to finish the proof is to invoke complex analysis: $u_x-iu_y$ is holomorphic and vanishes on a line segment, hence is identically zero.

(There ought to be a proof that works in higher dimensions, but I can't think of it now.)

#### Existence

To show existence fails in Q2, you can also use the reflection argument from above. If there is a solution with $f\equiv 0$, then $g$ is a restriction of a harmonic function to a line segment inside of its domain, hence $g$ must be real-analytic. So, existence fails for any function space that allows non-analytic functions.

Another approach is to consider a smaller rectangle $[0,1]\times [0,1/2]$ and solve the Dirichlet problem there with non-smooth data on the top boundary. Then take $f(x)=u(x,0)$ and $g(x)=u_y(x,0)$.  If there was a solution $v$ with this data, then by uniqueness $u\equiv v$. But then $u$ has a smooth extension beyond $[0,1]\times [0,1/2]$, a contradiction.

Comment: I suppose you mean the existence fails in Q2 not Q1?

Comment: Yes, corrected.

Comment: So basically the Cauchy problem is not only ill-posed, but also may bot actually solvable... Ok, maybe this is the reason that both Evans and Gilbarg&Trudinger does not contain this problem in their book...

Comment: Also, problem 2.2 in Gilbert and Trudinger is a good way to prove uniqueness. It is a very good exercise!

Comment: An underlying reason is that $u_{yy}=-u_{xx}$ amplifies high frequencies, similar to backward heat equation. So a Fourier series that converged originally (for $y=0$) stops being convergent for large $y$.